# load packages in a loop via `library()`

Tags: r, package

Instead of loading 30 packages each with the library function is it possible to do this in a loop?

```
pckgs = c("readr", "dplyr")
sapply(pckgs, library)
```

**Background:**

Before loading, i test if the packages are installed. For doing so i already have the package names in the form of `c("readr", ..., "dplyr")` and was wondering if i can also load the package in a loop instead of writing 30 times `library()`.

**What i tried:**

I simplified to one package:

```
sapply("readr", library)
sapply("readr", function(lib) library(lib))
sapply("readr", function(lib) library(get(lib)))
```

**Spoiler:**

I wanted to post this question and then decided to check for a "force character" in the parameter and got lucky. (It is a bit weird asking a question and answering it yourself, but when i read this i felt motivated enough :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: oh wow - didnt find that, sry. Will delete. Thanks! [Edit: Cant delete - approved duplicate,...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `character.only` can be used for that.

**Example:**

```
pckgs = c("readr", "dplyr")
sapply(pckgs, library, character.only = TRUE)
```